# Template problem in my super class with a struct definition

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have a problem. My base class "ABC" has two template classes A and B. My class "superABC" inherit ABC but the second template is fix on string. In ABC there is a struct named "structABC". In superABC is a function that return an instance from structABC. When I try to write the implementation of this function, the compiler give me

> C2244 error "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration".

Can someone say me what the problem is?

```
//ABC.h
#pragma once
template<class A, class B>
class ABC
{
public:
    void func();
    struct structABC {

    };

    structABC _referenceRange;
};

//superABC.h
#pragma once
#include "ABC.h"
#include "string.h"
template<class A>
class superABC:
    public ABC<A, string>
{
public:
    typename ABC<A, string>::structABC getBCD();
};

//superABC.cpp
#include "superABC.h"
template<class A>
inline typename ABC<A, string>::structABC superABC<A>::getBCD()
{
    return ABC<A, string>::structABC();
}
```

Comment: And what is this "C2244" error? Please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question body. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Sorry. I added the error message

Comment: `return ABC<A, string>::BCD();` I don't see a function called `BCD` anywhere.

Comment: Also, implementing templates in cpp files is probably going to cause problems.

Comment: You declare the function as non-inline, but define it as inline. That could be a cause of the mismatch.

Comment: Inline wasn't the problem. I tried it, but the error is still there.
ChrissMM my fault. In my small programm the struct is named BCD but after I write my question I thought it is not a godd idea to named it BCD. I change it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MSVC bug to me; the original code compiles with clang. As a workaround, add a typedef for `ABC<A, string>::structABC`, like this:

```
template<class A>
class superABC : public ABC<A, string>
{
    using structABC = typename ABC<A, string>::structABC;
public:
    structABC getBCD();
};

template<class A>
typename superABC<A>::structABC superABC<A>::getBCD()
{
    return structABC();
}
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/EIV48430)

Comment: Thank you, Igor, After I used the using statement, the compiler doesn't show me any errors.